# Clock in C: Time light up

Tags: c, colors, clock

For school I have to do a assignment, Im busy with it for like 3 weeks now and still havn't gotten far. We need to make a clock that has to be round and the colours of the seconds minutes AND hours need to light up. So if it's 4:25 am those numbers need to light up.

This is what I've got right now:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <windows.h>

    int csecs (int cseconds );

    void main (int sec, int min){
    printf("Hallo! Veel plezier met het bekijken van de tijd!");
    getch();
        while (sec)
            {
            time_t cseconds;
            cseconds = time (NULL);
            printf ("De Tijd: ");
            printf ("%d:", csecs( cseconds )/60/60%24+1);
            printf ("%d:", csecs( cseconds )/60%60 );
            printf ("%d", csecs( cseconds )%60 );

            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
        }

    }

    int csecs (int cseconds)
    {
        return cseconds;

    }
```

Can anyone tell me how I could possibly do this? I'm not asking you to do my homework.. I just really need some help.

Comment: This: `void main (int sec, int min)` is not a correct prototype for the `main()` function. Please see any reference for the allowed set of prototypes, and pick the one best for your program.

Comment: There is no code to draw a clock in there. You surely must have received some documentation on how to draw things in your applications. Why don't you try starting with that. I'm voting to close this until you have a concrete question and not just a very broad wish on being helped.

Comment: We do not have any documentation. We have to help each other, and search on the internet.. It's not a very broad question, I'm asking how to do the colours. But Im guessing that is not possible with this code?..

Comment: Digital or Analog clock? What are you "drawing" with? OpenGL? ASCII art? What do you mean by "light up"? Your main is invalid and your only function defined does nothing. Maybe a little clarification and a little more effort is required...

Comment: Sorry Mike, I use Code::Blocks. With light up I mean that for example it's 12:30 than it should show those numbers in e.g red. and the rest white. It doesn't have to be round it may also be straight like this:
hours: 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ect and than the hour that it is at that moment has to have a colour.

Comment: @lepel100 - Got it, sounds like you want to know how to put color on the Windows cmd prompt. That I can help with, then you can apply your "clock" to it and give the task another try

Comment: @lepel100 - FYI, if my answer didn't solve your problem you can re-edit your post with a lot more detail (at least everything here in the comments) and flag it asking a Mod to reopen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so based on your comments it sounds like you're using Windows and you really just want to set a color. That's pretty easy. You want the SetConsoleTextAttribute() function, here's a very quick example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");  // Print white text on black output
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED);
    printf("Hello Again!\n");  // Print Red text on black output
    getchar(); // Pause the program to admire the colors
}
```

For further highlighting you can also change the back ground, you can OR (`|`) together flags to get different colors and different back/fore grounds.

So if you wanted to do red text on a green back ground (for some reason) you could do:

```
FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN
```

[image]

I think that's all you were really asking for, now you can take that and apply it to your clock, getting the time and highlighting the color.